# An issue about the grammar of the assignment-expression

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Please consider the below example

```cpp
struct Test{
   Test(int){}
};
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  bool c = true;
  Test t = c?a:b = 1;
}
```

All [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/av3jTY) agree that this statement `Test t = c?a:b = 1;` is well-formed. However I have doubt for this result.

First, for this text `Test t = c?a:b = 1;`, it's a declaration, which has an initializer, such an initializer has the form:

> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>
> > = initializer-clause

> **initializer-clause** is either
>
> > assignment-expression or
> > braced-init-list

In my example, the `initializer-clause` should be `assignment-expression` which is denoted by text `c?a:b = 1`, and an valid `assignment-expression` shall satisfy one of these grammars:

> assignment-expression
>
> > - conditional-expression
> > - logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
> > - throw-expression

For this text `c?a:b = 1`, the `assignment-operator` is `=` and the `initializer-clause` is `1` which is literal(one kind of primary-expression, i.e, an valid `initializer-clause`).

What I can't understand is here, the left part of `=` shall be an **logical-or-expression**. However in my example, the left part is `c?a:b` which is a conditional expression. In other words, I can't find any valid form in grammar tree of **logical-or-expression** which can denote `c?a:b`. Namely, **conditional-expression** is not subsumed into **logical-or-expression**.

That means, this assignment-expression `c?a:b = 1` should have be ill-formed. But all compilers say that it's well-formed, how to interpret this? why the text `c?a:b = 1` can be as a valid `assignment-expression`?

Comment: `c?a:b = 1` **doesn't** match *logical-or-expression* *assignment-operator* *initializer-clause*, it matches *conditional-expression*

Comment: @Caleth you're right. the precedence of the conditional-expression is higher than that of assignment-expression. So `c?a:b = 1` is equivalent to `c?a:(b = 1)` rather than `(c?a:b) = 1`.

Comment: That's backwards: we say that expressions have precedence based on the rules of the grammar. If there wasn't *conditional-expression*, `c?a:b = 1` wouldn't be legal C++. There's no production of *logical-or-expression* that can match `c?a:b`

Comment: @Caleth  Exactly.